# discord.js if date.now() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get the current date (day, hour, minute, second) and put it in an if() statement to compare it with the date entered. But how am I able to get the date and ask for it in code?

This is what I got so far:

```
    bot.on("ready", () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();

    var currentdate = date + time

    var endDate = new Date('2021-01-21T14:00:00')

    if (endDate = currentdate) {
        console.log('The time has come..')
    } else {
        console.log('The time is coming soon..')
    }

})
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add some more details.

Comment: I want the bot to check what today's date is and what time it is. After that the bot should check if the current time & date matches the given time & date. If the current time & date matches with the specificed time, the bot should log "now" in the console.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I already tried to get the current date and the current time. This works perfectly. But now I want to check if the current date & time is equal to the given time.

Comment: Can u open this question i can answer ur question

Comment: I am not able to reopen it. I have a one week cooldown for asking questions.. and more. Maybe send me a hastebin link with your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'moment.js' like this :

```
  const moment = require("moment");

  getDifferenceInYear(date_1, date_2) {
    return moment(date_1).diff(moment(date_2), "years");
  }

  getDifferenceInDay(date_1, date_2) {
    return moment(date_1).diff(moment(date_2), "days");
  }

  getDifferenceInHour(date_1, date_2) {
    return moment(date_1).diff(moment(date_2), "hour");
  }

  getDifferenceInSecond(date_1, date_2) {
    return moment(date_1).diff(moment(date_2), "second");
  }

  isNowBetween(startDate, endDate) {
    return moment(new Date()).isBetween(startDate, endDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can following this code for comparing:

```
let inputDate = '2021-01-21T14:00:00'

let endDate =  Math.round(new Date(inputDate ) / 1000);
let cuurentDate = Math.round(new Date() / 1000)

if (cuurentDate  == endDate ) {
        console.log('The time has come..')
    }
else {
        console.log('The time is coming soon..')
    }
```